# Identity regarding "n choose k" (and the MGF of the negative binomial distribution)

Tags: statistics

How can ${2r+x-1}\choose{r-1}$ be manipulated to "something" on a form involving ${r+x-1}\choose {r-1}$?

This is related to a question regarding the MGF of the random variable $r + X$, where we have a negative binomial distribution.

Perhaps I'm on the wrong track... what I got is $M_{r+x}(t)=\sum e^{t(r+x)} {{2r+x-1} \choose {r-1}} p^r {(1-p)}^{r+x}$... I just substituted $r+x$ for $y$ in the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't substitute $r+x$ in that way.

Let $Y = r + X$ where $X$ is negative binomial with parameters $r$ and $p$.  Moreover, let $X$ have support on $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$; i.e., $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{r+x-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^x, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}.$$  This parametrization is consistent with what you wrote.

Then $$M_Y(t) = M_{r+X}(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{t(r+X)}] = \operatorname{E}[e^{tr} e^{tX}] = e^{tr} \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = e^{tr} M_X(t).$$  That is to say, the MGF of $Y$ is simply $e^{tr}$ multiplied by the MGF of $X$.

The direct MGF calculation would be
$$M_Y(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{t(r+X)}] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{t(r+x)} \Pr[X = x] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{t(r+x)} \binom{r+x-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^x.$$  You cannot write $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{t(r+x)} \binom{2r+x-1}{r-1} p^r(1-p)^{r+x}$$ because the formula for the expectation of a function of $X$ is $$\operatorname{E}[g(X)] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty g(x) \Pr[X = x],$$ not $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty g(x) \Pr[X = g(x)].$$  To see why this expression is obviously false, note that the choice $g(x) = x+1/2$ would lead to the obviously wrong expression $$\operatorname{E}[X + 1/2] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty (x + 1/2) \Pr[X = x + 1/2] = 0,$$ since if $X$ is integer-valued, $\Pr[X = x + 1/2] = 0$ for any integer $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have misunderstood the formula for the MGF (which made it much more easy to solve...)